# Discover Kubernetes annotations to generate ConfigMap

Tags: kubernetes

I am forced to use a certain API Gateway which does (unlike traefik) not support service discovery based on labels or annotations.
What are the required steps / resources:

- to discover annotations of microservices deployed to my cluster
- act upon a change in the annotation
- write a ConfigMap back to the cluster

I was imagining something like [stakater/Reloader](https://github.com/stakater/Reloader). There I can see basically the Go project and some permissions to read the existing resources in the cluster.
Any tips, points in the right direction / tutorials on how to tackle this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This question is quite broad. It sounds like you want to write a [controller](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/architecture/controller/) to monitor pods and generate configmaps in response to pod annotations. [This article](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2021/06/21/writing-a-controller-for-pod-labels/) discusses one possible way of implementing a controller.

Comment: @mxcd Is your issue  solved ? If yes, can you provide the resolution steps you have followed and provide it as an answer for the greater visibility of the community.